ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API : deployment error: deployment completed, but with errors
I am trying to deploy an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API to AWS Beanstalk using AWS CodePipeline with both build and deploy stage and source code is on Github. Now my build stage seems to be working with a success message but the deploy stage is failing with the error:

Deployment completed, but with errors: During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version. Failed to deploy application. Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0aa02c41a8683f9a7'. Aborting the operation. [Instance: i-0aa02c41a8683f9a7 ConfigSet: Infra-WriteRuntimeConfig, Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild, Hook-PreAppDeploy, Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild, Hook-EnactAppDeploy, Hook-PostAppDeploy] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: null. Error occurred during build: Command hooks failed Deployment Failed: Unexpected Exception

I am not able to understand what the problem is, am I making a mistake in the buildspec.yml file, or is it something else.
This my buildspec file for reference:
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      dotnet: 8.0
    commands:
      - echo "Installing .NET Core 8.0"

  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo "Restoring .NET packages"
      - dotnet restore IndiaShoppingBackend.sln || exit 1

  build:
    commands:
      - echo "Building the .NET application"
      - dotnet build IndiaShoppingBackend.sln --configuration Release || exit 1
      - echo "Publishing the .NET application"
      - dotnet publish IndiaShoppingBackend/IndiaShoppingBackend.csproj --configuration Release --output ./output || exit 1

  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo "Zipping the output files"
      - zip -r output.zip ./output || exit 1
      - echo "Copying files to S3"
      - aws s3 cp output.zip s3://indiashoppingbackend-artifacts-bucket/output.zip || exit 1

artifacts:
  files:
    - output/**
  discard-paths: yes

FYI, I am using RDS for database hosting and I tested it locally and its working just fine.
Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.
I was trying to deploy backend ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API to aws beanstalk using codepipeline for ci/cd deployment.
The build stage worked but deployment failed

This error can happen from many reasons.  You need to take a look at the deployment logs and also show it here so we can solve the problem
